# Maven Cobertura plugin won't read parameters

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, cobertura

When calling the Maven goal

```
cobertura:clean -DforceMojoExecution=true -X
```

from within Eclipse on my project, the `forceMojoExecution` won't be applied.

The debug log contains the following line:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) forceMojoExecution = false
```

The same problem occurs on our [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) installation.

When calling

```
dependency:analyze -DfailOnWarning=true -X
```

on the same project, the parameter `failOnWarning` is correctly applied.

See [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) for the Maven Cobertura plugin. I'm using it in version 2.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set `forceMojoExecution` in the plugin configuration section in the `pom.xml`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <forceMojoExecution>true</forceMojoExecution>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See also [forceMojoExecution parameter changed to forceOpenJpaExecution?](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSQL-72).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cobertura plugin documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#forceMojoExecution), the value of this configuration is obtained from the expression `${cobertura.force}`. So the following should work:

```
mvn cobertura:clean -Dcobertura.force=true -X
```